# How do I check if the current date is within a month in advance of a specified date

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I have a billing system where users are allowed to renew if the expiry date is less than 1 month away.

For example, let's say a product expires on 03/10/2019. Today's date is 04/09/2019 so it's within the 30-day window and will be shown the message to renew. However, Monday's date (02/09/2019) or any date before that is not within the 30-day window and won't be shown the message.

Bearing in mind I'm using the UK date system DD-MM-YYYY.

Managed to construct an if statement to check if the current date is exactly 1 month away from the specified date but not within that time, which is what I need to do.

Scoured Google for this and could not find an answer. I might just be searching for the wrong thing, I don't know.

```
$current_date = date("d-m-Y");
$expiry_date = date_create("04-10-2019");
$month_prior_date = date_sub($expiry_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
$month_prior_date = date_format($month_prior_date, "d-m-Y");
if ($current_date == $month_prior_date) {
    echo "You are eligible for a renewal.";
}
```

Comment: 1 month is not always 30 days! So what do you need 30 days even if the month is 31 or 28 days ?

Comment: My mistake, I did mean 30 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My very basic solution is thus.

1. Get current date
2. Get the fixed expiry date
3. Check if expiry date is less than today's date
4. Activate renewal alert

PHP code sample

```
<?php
$current_date = date( "d-m-Y" );
$expiry_date = date( "d-m-Y", strtotime( "04-10-2019 -1 month" ) ); 
if ( $expiry_date <= $current_date ) {
    echo "You are eligible for a renewal.";
}
```

Test code and feedback.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Just changed -1 month to -30 days to avoid problems between different length months.

Answer (score 0):

A way :

```
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$expireDate = '02-10-2019';
$maxDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($expireDate. ' -30 days'));

if ($today <= $maxDate) {echo "Can Renew";} else {echo "Can not renew";}
```